# Date parsing error in logstash config file

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have following logstash config file

```
input { 
 tcp { type => "tcp_test" port => 1514 add_field => [ "log_type", "romote_log" ]}
}

filter {
  if [type] == "tcp_test" {
    grok {
       type => tcp_test
       match => [ "message", "%{WORD:client} %{WORD:app}" ]
    }
    date{
       match => ["timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss"]
       locale=>"en"
       target => "@timestamp"
      }




  }
}

output { 
elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

my input for this configuration is 
**dummy_computer from_leo_messi  2013-05-15-23:19:27   this is blah blah logs..**

and my output in kibana is 
[image]

I just want **2013-05-15-23:19:27** as time stamp.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your date filter is attempting to parse the "timestamp" field, but there is no such field. You'll have to adjust your grok filter accordingly. This works:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "message",
      "%{WORD:client} %{WORD:app} (?<timestamp>\S+) %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
    ]
    overwrite => ["message"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss"]
    remove_field => ["timestamp"]
  }
}
```

For an explanation of the "overwrite" option, see my answer to [logstash, syslog and grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930635/logstash-syslog-and-grok/26967531#26967531).

Comment: am getting like http://i.imgur.com/e1Lsdvs.png
for input "dummy_computer from_leo_messi  2013-05-15-23:19:27   this is blah blah logs.."
 i wish to get @timestamp = 2013-05-15-23:19:27
could you help me ?

Comment: If you're using the configuration I provided it's very hard to see how you would end up with that result. What was the exact input string you tested with?